# iframe video url returns blob_url in android 4.4.2 and in chrome

Tags: javascript, android, html, youtube

I am developing a video url detector app. I am able to fetch urls from youtube and other online video providers. In the case of 'iframe' too url is fetched. But in the case of android 4.4.2 and chrome browser the url was returning a blob_url.

- blob:http%3A//www.youtube.com/c09a053d-c7c2-4e79-ad39-f351120f864a"

The whole video tag given below

```
<video class="video-stream html5-main-video" x-webkit-airplay="allow" data-youtube-id="i4TA1SrZrwU" src="blob:http%3A//www.youtube.com/c09a053d-c7c2-4e79-ad39-f351120f864a" style="width: 560px; height: 315px; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-transform: none;"></video>
```

For the lower versions of android the 'src' from video tag returned similar url as given below

- http://r3---sn-ci5gup-jj0e.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?upn=zaSBvfPIygo&ip=xxx.xx.xxx.xx&ms=au&fexp=935660%2C938806%2C938653%2C914074%2C916625%2C932954%2C945517%2C937417%2C913434%2C936923%2C945044&mws=yes&source=youtube&itag=18&ipbits=0&sparams=id%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&mv=m&id=o-AAqw63RvGpvl0MaCTBaMvcudlVpU2Q0eokLTOuYn79B5&key=yt5&expire=1399572450&mt=1399548872&sver=3&ratebypass=yes&signature=A51047F5A290208DC111C88847EACE4A48ACC6D9.A299A789B554B736CC5D37AE7AC745C0DF5C7516&cpn=X_SKmUrR7RRpMAPx&ptk=youtube_none&pltype=contentugc&c=web&cver=html5

I've two qustions,

- Why the url is returning a blob_url?
- Is there any way to get the exact url as of the lower android versions?

Comment: did you get any answer of this question..
I am facing same problem i am injecting javascript in webview and i am getting youtube video blob url but i want the url which android lower version return..
if you solve this problem please let me know thanks.
are you able to play blob url in android?